# How to print numbers horizontally in line in Console?

Tags: c#, output, console-application

While I am using this code (below) with Visual Studio 2012, the answers are in vertical order.

How can I get answers in horizontal order using VS 2012

Below is my code that I getting output in vertical order: how may I achieve the same result in a horizontal manner?

Are there any settings in Visual Studio for getting output in horizontal or vertical?

```
class RandomNumbers
{
    private static Random random = new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = GenerateRandomNumbers(200,100,10);
        foreach (var temp in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(temp+" ");
        }
    }
    static IEnumerable<int> GenerateRandomNumbers(int NumberOfElements)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0,NumberOfElements-1).OrderBy(n=>random.Next());
    }
    static IEnumerable<int> GenerateRandomNumbers(int min, int max, int numberOfElement)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfElement - 1).Select(n => random.Next(max, min));
    }
}
```

Comment: By vertical, do you just mean that there are line feeds between the numbers?  If that is the case, just use `Console.Write` instead of `WriteLine`.  Other than that, i'm not sure what you mean by horizontal and vertical.

Comment: you are correct ,i dint think that way, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Write() instread of WriteLine()

```
class RandomNumbers
{
    private static Random random = new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = GenerateRandomNumbers(200,100,10);
        foreach (var temp in numbers)
        {
            Console.Write(temp+" ");
        }
    }
    static IEnumerable<int> GenerateRandomNumbers(int NumberOfElements)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0,NumberOfElements-1).OrderBy(n=>random.Next());
    }
    static IEnumerable<int> GenerateRandomNumbers(int min, int max, int numberOfElement)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfElement - 1).Select(n => random.Next(max, min));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just code Console.Write(); instead of Console.WriteLine().

Comment: ... which was already answered 7 years ago

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25585295/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*